Can I have a web application run along my WordPress hosted website?
I have a WordPress site runnning, the host of the website is from WordPress itself, but the host for the domain is from another company which also allows me to host custom-made websites.
The thing is that I don't know if I can run on the same domain the WordPress website and the web application.
Is this possible?
Right now, if I try to access the newly created files that are uploaded in the file manager of the domain host I get redirected to the Not Found default page from the WordPress website.

Please edit your question to clarify what you mean by "the host of the website is from WordPress itself". Are you referring to WordPress.com?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
